# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence with Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, sequence

I am trying to reproduce the [deep video portrait (2018)](https://web.stanford.edu/~zollhoef/papers/SG2018_DeepVideo/page.html) and they are referring [Isola (2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004.pdf) which implements patchGAN.

In patchGAN, the discriminator returns `[batch_size, patch_width, patch_height, 1]` of tensor and I'd like to feed this tensor to my loss defined as following:

```
EcGAN = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(D_real)+ tf.log(np.float32(1. - D_fake)))
```

So I comprised following pseudo operation checker and run:

```
sheudo_input = tf.Variable(np.float32(np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=[16, 30, 30, 1]))) 
EcGAN = tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(sheudo_input)+ tf.log(np.float32(1. - sheudo_input)))
```

But `EcGAN` not computed and reutrns error like this:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What would be the possible promblem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `np.float32` call is the problem. Numpy functions don't play nice with tensors unless on eager execution mode.

When attempting to cast, you should use `tf.cast`. Or in this case, the result should be a float *anyway*, so this is enough:

```
tf.log(sheudo_input) + tf.log(1. - sheudo_input)
```